Is it possible to create a table and display it earlier in the document?
Would it be possible to write some text, then create a table, but insert this table before that text? Kind of like teleporting the table to earlier in the document? I'm not interested in table referencing etc., I mean literally replace the entire table.
EDIT
The comments desired a practical example, I deliver.
Based on the suggestion of @Rmano I was able to make a decent MWE showing my wishes.
The MWE below shows how I wish to use a value calculated in the second table to be used in the first table.
Using the \teleport command hinted at an interesting concept, now I just need to be able to "hide" the first time I called \teleport.
Or maybe there's a simpler way altogether?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\teleport}{

\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{lr}}
@ Items & @ Subtotal \\\hline
@ Item 1 & 2 \\
@ Item 2 & 3 \\\hline
@ Total & sum(b2:b3) tag(val)
\end{spreadtab}
\STmakegtag{val}
\end{center}

}

\teleport

\section{Main account}

\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{lr}}
@ Accounts & @ Subtotal \\\hline
@ Subaccount 1 & \STtag{val} \\
@ Subaccount 2 & 3 \\\hline
@ Total & sum(b2:b3)
\end{spreadtab}
\end{center}

\section{Sub account 1}

\teleport

\end{document}


The solution
In case anyone is ever looking for the same answer, with help of @Rmano and @egreg I found this to be working.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{spreadtab}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\usevalue}[1]{%
  \ifcsname usevalue@#1\endcsname
    \csname usevalue@#1\endcsname
  \else
    0
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\definevalue}[2]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \write\@auxout{%
      \global\string\@namedef{usevalue@#1}{#2}%
    }%
  }\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{lr}}
@ Items & @ Subtotal \\\hline
@ Item 1 & \usevalue{myval} \\
@ Item 2 & 3 \\\hline
@ Total & sum(b2:b3) tag(val)
\end{spreadtab}
\STmakegtag{val}
\end{center}

\definevalue{myval}{\STtag{val}}

\end{document}


Interesting question, but please add an MWE.

If you explain why you cannot create the table in the place it must be put, you could receive better suggestions.

Giving the discussion in comments, maybe you want to reuse this solution from @egreg:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%%% ideas from @egreg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/416272/38080
\makeatletter
\newcommand\saveforbefore[2]{
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
        \unexpanded{\global\@namedef{teleport@#1}{#2}}%
    }
}
\newcommand\usefromlater[1]{%
    \ifcsname teleport@#1\endcsname
        \csname teleport@#1\endcsname
    \else
        Hmmm... rerun!
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

    This is text, where we used the future value \usefromlater{lilla}

    The value is defined later, here\dots 
    \saveforbefore{lilla}{3}

\end{document}

In the first run, you'll have

...and then, after the second run:

previous answer
I am not sure I understand your question. TeX processes linearly the input stream, but with multiple compilations, you can do almost everything. I am trying to answer to what I understood, hoping to help you refine the question...
Anyway, what about teleporting  the text after the table?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

    This is text.

    \newcommand\teleport{%
    This is text to be teleported after the table.
    }

    \begin{table}[h]\caption{Look ma, a table!}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            a & b & c \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \teleport
\end{document}



very interesting! Tho in my case I have this value that must be calculated first but displayed later, which forces me to call the \teleport command already before. Any ideas on how to circumvent this?

@Steven why do you need to move whole paragraphs or whole tables, your description in the previous comment sounds as if you should calculate the value, save it in a command \foo then use \foo later, which is just normal latex cprocessing.

@DavidCarlisle because the value calculated in the second table is to be used in the first table. But the first table cannot yet access the value, because it has not been calculated yet due to TeX linearly processing the input stream.

this is quite normal and is for example how ``\pagerefor\ref` work, you can reference values not known at that point and will be picked up on the next run but it's simpler to think of it as referencing the value rather than moving the table (or you could implement either) @Steven

@DavidCarlisle I was thinking of something like that too. Actually, I asked about this in another question referenced below. I would have no clue how to properly/cleanly implement this though, which is why I'm looking for alternatives.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/723592/how-can-i-use-a-tagged-value-earlier-in-the-document-using-spreadtab

@DavidCarlisle sorry... ;-P

@Rmano this is great! We're on to something here! There's one issue: the value I want to save in the AUX file is accessible as \STtag{someTag}, so by calling \saveforbefore{lilla}{\STtag{someTag}} what's written in the AUX file is \global \@namedef {teleport@lilla}{\STtag {val}}, which is not helpful. If only I could expand the tag before writing it to the AUX file... I noticed that if I replace \STtag {val} in the AUX file by a number, it does work! I tried to expand before writing but I'm no good at this, could you take another look please?

@Rmano oh, I just noticed that I cannot use \usefromlater{lilla} in the spreadtab table. It results in an ! FP error: Evaluation results in multiple values!. error :-( any clues?

It can work if I use \FPeval{lilla}{\usefromlater{lilla}} B-) There's still potential!

You have to take care of expansion here... Probably your \STtag is not exandaple, or whatever. You can try \edef\tmp{\STtag{some tag}}\saveforbefore{lilla}{\tmp} or some expandafter trick...

A few hours later and I still haven't figured it out. I tried any combination of \expandafter before-between-within \saveforbefore but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Never mind, this question explains how
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520174/expand-variable-name-before-writing-to-aux-file?rq=1
Thanks for the help everyone!
